# Python:GPG Encryption without receipt

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I have received Public key for encryption, but no key_recipient

**Issue:** TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Below is the code for Airflow, I have given `key_recipient=None`, but it's failing

For some requirement, we get key_recipient and it works fine, but this requirement doesn't have key_receipt

**Code:**

```
class EncryptGPG(BaseOperator):
 
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                s3_bucket,
                s3_key,
                key,
                key_recipient=None,
                *args,
                **kwargs):
        self.s3_bucket = s3_bucket
        self.s3_key = s3_key
        self.s3_conn_id = s3_conn_id
        self.key_recipient = key_recipient
        self.key = key  

    def encrypt_file(self, file_path, key_path , key_recipient):
        """Encrypt the file and Upload into s3"""

        try:
            gpg = gnupg.GPG()
            key_data = base64.b64decode(key_path).decode()
            import_result = gpg.import_keys(key_data)

            with open(file_path, 'r+b') as f:
                status = gpg.encrypt_file(
                    file=f,
                    recipients=[key_recipient],
                    output=f.name,
                    always_trust=True
                )
```

Comment: Maybe I'm off by miles when it comes to Python, but have you tried an empty list `[]` instead of a list with a parameter that hasn't been offered?

Comment: Yes empty list as I don't have receipts